# `min()` is not working properly in Python?

Tags: python, math, min

I am new to Python and notice the following error when using `min()`.

```
import pandas as pd
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(min(20, pd.array(a)**2))
```

The code should return[1, 4, 9, 16, 20], however, it returns [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]. It seems that `min()` is not working as expected. What is the reason and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Python’s `min` does not apply values over arrays. It gives you which it thinks is the smaller of the two arguments you pass it.

Comment: @deceze Thanks. How should I fix my code? I'd like to compare 20 and the square of an array, and then keep the smaller value.

Comment: You know 5**2 = 25, right? Or did i miss understand it. Do you want all number in the list where its smaller then 20 or do you want to replace the last number with 20? I think in that way because the min() function is for collecting the smallest number on a (for example) list, array, etc.

Comment: I’m not very familiar with pandas, there’s probably a pandas way to do it. Tag your question accordingly if you want to attract people who may know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`min` in Python operates on scalar values, not collections of values. That said, `pandas` is built on a base of `numpy`, and `numpy` *does* offer an element-wise minimum function of this sort, so by mixing `pandas` and `numpy` you can get what you expect:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # Get numpy as well

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

# Creates a pandas array, but gets element-wise minimums via numpy.minimum
print(np.minimum(20, pd.array(a)**2))
```

which, on [the W3Schools `pandas` interpreter](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/trypandas.asp?filename=demo_pandas_editor) I just loaded to verify, outputs:

```
<IntegerArray>
[1, 4, 9, 16, 20]
Length: 5, dtype: Int64
```

Somewhat surprisingly, but conveniently, this even returns a new `pandas` array, not a `numpy` array; the integration between the two of them is deep enough that you keep your expected types even through the non-`pandas` function.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = pd.array(a)**2 < 20
c = []

for i in b:
    if i == True:
        c.append(a[i])
print(min(c))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**